# Debian 8 - Lan connection works but no internet [Unknown host]

Tags: linux, debian, dns

I have a Debian 8 server that has been running great for about a year. All of a sudden I am no longer getting internet access.

The server is connected over an ethernet cable and I can SSH into over the local network.

When I do ping `www.google.com` then I get Unknown Host. If I do ping 8.8.8.8 then it works.

So I would guess that it is a DNS issue? My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this..

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Where else should I be lookgin to resolve this?

Comment: What does it show in `/etc/resolv.conf `?

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf is blank

Comment: Weird that it would become blank.  Do you have any configuration management software in your environment, and are you hosting your own DNS servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try updating your `/etc/resolv.conf` file with the following:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search local
```

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google's public DNS servers as you seem to already be aware of.

> nameserver Name server IP address
>
> > Internet address of a name server that the resolver should
> >                   query, either an IPv4 address (in dot notation), or an IPv6
> >                   address in colon (and possibly dot) notation as per RFC 2373.
> >                   Up to MAXNS (currently 3, see ) name servers may be
> >                   listed, one per keyword.  If there are multiple servers, the
> >                   resolver library queries them in the order listed.  If no
> >                   nameserver entries are present, the default is to use the name
> >                   server on the local machine.  (The algorithm used is to try a
> >                   name server, and if the query times out, try the next, until
> >                   out of name servers, then repeat trying all the name servers
> >                   until a maximum number of retries are made.)

---

> search Search list for host-name lookup.
>
> > The search list is normally determined from the local domain
> >                   name; by default, it contains only the local domain name.
> >                   This may be changed by listing the desired domain search path
> >                   following the search keyword with spaces or tabs separating
> >                   the names.  Resolver queries having fewer than ndots dots
> >                   (default is 1) in them will be attempted using each component
> >                   of the search path in turn until a match is found.  For
> >                   environments with multiple subdomains please read options
> >                   ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and
> >                   unnecessary traffic for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this
> >                   process may be slow and will generate a lot of network traffic
> >                   if the servers for the listed domains are not local, and that
> >                   queries will time out if no server is available for one of the
> >                   domains.
> >                   The search list is currently limited to six domains with a
> >                   total of 256 characters.

[resolv.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)

Comment: Thank you that did it. This server has reached EOL so it only has to survive for another 3 weeks. This will do until then :)  Thanks for your solution, much appreciated